# Is there an 'OR' equivalent to PTEST in x64 assembly?

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, x86-64, intel

In x64 assembly, [PTEST %XMM0 -> %XMM1](http://siyobik.info.gf/main/reference/instruction/PTEST) sets the zero-flag if none of the same bits are set in %XMM0 and %XMM1, and sets the carry-flag if everything that is set in %XMM0 is also set in %XMM1:

```
IF (SRC[127:0] bitwiseAND DEST[127:0] = 0)
    ZF = 1;
ELSE
    ZF = 0;
FI;
IF (SRC[127:0] bitwiseAND (bitwiseNOT DEST[127:0]) = 0)
    CF = 1;
ELSE
    CF = 0;
FI;
DEST[127:0] Unmodified;
AF = OF = PF = SF = 0;
```

I frequently find myself wanting a flag that will be set if any bits are set in either %XMM0 **or** %XMM1. You can do this in two instructions with:

```
POR %XMM0 -> %XMM1
PTEST %XMM1, %XMM1
```

But this takes an extra cycle of latency.  I have a case right now where I'd really like to save that cycle.  Is there a faster way of doing this? Or some obvious way I'm missing of doing this using PTEST?  I'm hoping there is some hidden equivalent of:

```
PTEST_OR %XMM0, %XMM1
```

Does this exist?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  If you can generate your conditions inverted, (so you're looking for either=zero instead of either=one), might be able to use PTEST, because that's what AND does.